# How to use mongoose alias with typed Schema signature

Tags: typescript, mongoose

**TS interface**

```
interface User {
name:string,
address:string
}
```

**mongoose Schema**

```
const userSchema = new Schema<User>({
name: {type:string},
a:{type:string, alias:'address'} //ERROR - a doesn't exist on user
})
```

One fix is to not use the <T> signature but then you lose IntelliSense. Is there a workaround to use an alias (use 'a' in the database but have 'address' in code) with the typed signature?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you could do the following.

Create schema:

```
const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: String,
    a: {
      type: String,
      alias: "address",
    }
  }
);
```

Create type for all the aliases in the schema:

```
type UserAliases = {
  address: string;
};
```

Create inferred type for User based on the schema and aliases:

```
type User = InferSchemaType<typeof userSchema> & UserAliases;
```

Create user model:

```
const UserModel = model<User>("User", userSchema);
```

Now you can use either "a" or "address" in typescript while persisting "a" to the database.